# Electric potential between 2 charged spheres -- problems with sign?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, conventions

I'm trying to find the electric potential between 2 nested spheres. The outer one has $R_1$ and $Q_1$; the inner one has $R_2$ and $Q_2$. I know the potential at $R_1$ is $\frac{Q_1+Q_2}{R_1}$by Gauss's law, but I'm struggling with finding the potential at $R_2$. An online resource says:

[image]

But the directionality is confusing me. We take the integral moving outward from $R_1$ to $R_2$, so $ds$ points inward. But the electric field has to point outwards, so $E*ds$ should be negative, so the quantity on line 2 should be positive. Where is my thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The quantity in line $2$ is positive.

What is $\vec E \cdot d\vec s$?

It is $E \hat r \cdot dr \hat r = E \, dr$ where $E$ and $dr$ are components in the $\hat r$ direction

What does $dr$ mean?

It is $\Delta r = r_{\rm final} - r_{\rm initial}$ making that interval smaller and smaller.

How does one decide on the values of $r_{\rm final}$ and $r_{\rm initial}$?

They are shown by the limits of integration so in this case consider a small but finite displacement $\Delta r$ which is equivalent to writing $\displaystyle \int ^{r_{\rm final}} _{r_{\rm initial}} E \,\Delta r = E\, (r_{\rm final} - r_{\rm initial})$

$\vec E = \dfrac {Q_2}{r^2} \hat i$ so $E = +\dfrac {Q_2}{r^2}$ ie it is a quantity whose sign depends on the sign of $Q_2$.

Note that there is nothing to say whether the displacement is towards or away from the charge $Q_2$ until one decides on the values of $r_{\rm final}$ and $r_{\rm initial}$.

If $r_{\rm final} < r_{\rm initial}$ then $\displaystyle \int ^{r_{\rm final}} _{r_{\rm initial}} E \,\Delta r = E\, (r_{\rm final} - r_{\rm initial})$ is negative.

The quantity $\displaystyle \int ^{r_{\rm final}} _{r_{\rm initial}} E \,\Delta r$ is the work done by the electric field and as the change in potential is define as **minus** the work done by the electric field the quantity on the right hand side of line $2$ is positive.